# Social tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, facebook-like

I'm using this example script, provided by Google inside a rails app (so it's compiled by Rails into a single JS file with all my other scripts):

```
_ga.trackSocial = function(opt_pageUrl, opt_trackerName) {
  _ga.trackFacebook(opt_pageUrl, opt_trackerName);
  _ga.trackTwitter(opt_pageUrl, opt_trackerName);
};


/**
 * Tracks Facebook likes, unlikes and sends by suscribing to the Facebook
 * JSAPI event model. Note: This will not track facebook buttons using the
 * iFrame method.
 * @param {string} opt_pageUrl An optional URL to associate the social
 *     tracking with a particular page.
 * @param {string} opt_trackerName An optional name for the tracker object.
 */
_ga.trackFacebook = function(opt_pageUrl, opt_trackerName) {
  var trackerName = _ga.buildTrackerName_(opt_trackerName);
  try {
    if (FB && FB.Event && FB.Event.subscribe) {
      FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl) {
        _gaq.push([trackerName + '_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like',
            targetUrl, opt_pageUrl]);
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(targetUrl) {
        _gaq.push([trackerName + '_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'unlike',
            targetUrl, opt_pageUrl]);
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe('message.send', function(targetUrl) {
        _gaq.push([trackerName + '_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'send',
            targetUrl, opt_pageUrl]);
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {}
};
```

Then, this code to load my Facebook like button:

```
<div id="fb-root" class="fb_like"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=...&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="http://somethingunderthewater.com" send="true" layout="standard" colorscheme="light" width="400" show_faces="false" font="trebuchet ms"></fb:like>
```

But while Google tracks the +1 button, it's not tracking any Facebook like events and I really don't know enough about JS to figure out what's wrong. I see the note about the iFrame method, but don't think that's how my code is loading -- maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Facebook provides Facebook Insight tool for Facebook analytics. Google Analytics doesn't work well with Facebook and the reason is not hard to guess :)

Comment: Make sure you're initializing the Facebook JS SDK properly. Try running another FB JS API action and see if it returns good results. And like Mikko said, FB doesn't like to work with outside analytics - but it is theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this script before the button:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">_ga.trackFacebook();</script>
```

right after

```
   <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=...&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
```